# Swift CollectionView scrolls out of bounds

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uicollectionview, layer

I have a `CollectionView` and the problem is that I have to set `.masksToBounds = false` so my `Cells` are displayed properly (their `shadow` to be specific). However that causes the `CollectionView` to scroll out of bounds which I certainly don't want. Is there a way to maybe only set `maskstToBounds` on the `left` and `right` ? Or is there any other workaround that might solve my issue here?

[image]

As you can see it scrolls at the top even though I set the `theCollectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 30)`

I hope my problem is clear. If you need any more info just let me know.

Answer (score 1):

you have two problem, right?

first, you want set the shadow in a specific part

```swift
layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 2, height: 0)
```

If you want shadows only on the left and right, you can set the height at zero.

second, you want to set position

```swift
theCollectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
theCollectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 30).isActive = true
```